# Error playing audio file from Windows Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, audio-streaming, azure-blob-storage

I have an audio file stored in Windows Azure blob storage. The file is m4a and the content/mime type is set to audio/mp4. When accessing the file in Chrome or jPlayer the file plays fine once but then after refuses to play:

http://foundbite.blob.core.windows.net/foundbites/3992901812.m4a

Is there something I could be doing wrong with the blob settings? Having looked around there were some mentions of range requests being disabled but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you come up with an easier solution than using windows azure media services?

Comment: In the end we just used Azure Storage and we got it to repeat, unfortunately I can't remember too many specifics.

Comment: No worries.  I'm running into a strange issue where the audio plays fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome (it only plays for 90 seconds) - can you share an audio URL from your storage? perhaps I can diff the request/response headers.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately we shut the product down but I've just consulted the code and I do remember having a problem with Firefox. Instead of playing mp4 we converted all our files to OGG as well and used these for Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the live streaming or for the media files I suggest that you work with the Windows Azure Media Services http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+azure+media+services&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IE10TR

it is based on Windows Azure Unstructured storage, the BLOB Storage but this service is specially designed for the media content that you can store on Windows Azure Storage.

I hope this helps let me know if you need anything else